# App works on emulator, crashes on device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, emulation, device

I've got a weird problem. i'm coding app, which uses XML from the Web. On Emulator it's all fine, but on the phone it crashes (it closes after clicking button, there are not any alerts).

Here is the code:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Xml;

namespace KursyWalut
{
 [Activity (Label = "KursyWalut", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
 public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
   protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
   {
     base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Popularne);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.przycisk);
        TextView data = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.data);
        TextView kurs = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.kurs);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = FindViewById<RadioGroup> (Resource.Id.radioGroup);
        RadioButton dolar = FindViewById <RadioButton> (Resource.Id.rbDolar);
        RadioButton euro = FindViewById <RadioButton> (Resource.Id.rbEuro);
        RadioButton frank = FindViewById <RadioButton> (Resource.Id.rbFrank);
        int checkedRadioButton;

        XmlDocument dokument = new XmlDocument ();

        //  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        button.Click += delegate {
            try{
                dokument.Load("http://nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.MakeText(this,"Brak połaczenia z Internetem!",ToastLength.Long);
            }
            data.Text = "Data: " + getDocumentDate(dokument);

            checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
            switch(checkedRadioButton){

            case Resource.Id.rbDolar:
                kurs.Text = "Kurs USD: " + getRate(dokument,"USD");
                break;

            case Resource.Id.rbEuro:
                kurs.Text = "Kurs EUR: " + getRate(dokument,"EUR");
                break;

            case Resource.Id.rbFrank:
                kurs.Text = "Kurs CHF: " + getRate(dokument,"CHF");
                break;
            }
        };
    }
    String getDocumentDate(XmlDocument xml){
        return xml.SelectSingleNode("/tabela_kursow/data_publikacji").InnerText;
    }

    String getRate(XmlDocument xml, String currency){
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xml.DocumentElement) {

            if (xmlNode.Name == "pozycja") {
                if (xmlNode.SelectSingleNode ("kod_waluty").InnerText == currency)
                    return xmlNode.SelectSingleNode ("kurs_sredni").InnerText;      
            }
        }
        return "Nie znaleziono kursu";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the Internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: yes, it is set in android manifest

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at `Toast.MakeText(this,"Brak połaczenia z Internetem!",ToastLength.Long);`, what kind of exception is `Exception ex`?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I found it. You're currently reading the document in your button.Click. You should try doing it in a background thread. With the *Task Parallel Library* for example:

```
        XmlDocument dokument = new XmlDocument ();

        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                dokument.Load("http://nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Brak połaczenia z Internetem!", ToastLength.Long);
            }
        });
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. if i code this like your suggestion i have nullpointerexception in method getRate(). i really don't know why it doesn't work, on emulator it works fine :(

Comment: Where are you receiving a nullpointer exactly? (What object is null?)

Comment: I got Exception warning in such a line foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xml.DocumentElement). I think that xml wasn't loaded yet, but the main thread used it in some methods. have i to synchronise that threads somehow?

Comment: `xml.DocumentElement` is the root node of the XML, it's not a collection. Perhaps you can read yourself into the `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there's an exception in `dokument.Load()`, it will fall through the catch handler and your code will continue to run, even if the document is not loaded. You should probably change your catch handler to:

```c#
try
{
    // read xml into string
    var xml = new System.Net.WebClient()
        .DownloadString("http://nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml");
    dokument.LoadXml(xml);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Toast
        .MakeText(this, "Brak połaczenia z Internetem! " + ex, ToastLength.Long)
        .Show();
    return;
}
```

Notice I added the `.Show()` at the end of `MakeText()`. Otherwise, you won't see the actual Toast. I also added the actual exception.

I have a feeling you're getting an exception loading the document. Once you determine the cause, the rest should be easier to figure out.

Comment: thanks for helping. after putting your code into mine i get Toast message on my screen and later something like that.
System.XML.XmlException: Unexpected declaration markup was found... and later at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadDeclaration()[0x00000] <filename unknown> . The problem is that the xml wasn't loaded? how to solve that, to load xml properly at the beggining of the program?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're getting valid XML. That exception only occurs if it parses <! followed by some invalid character (which I don't see in the link you provided)[1] 

I would recommend that you first try to read the XML into a string, then try to load it. See edits I made. Put a breakpoint on the `LoadXml()` call, so you can see what the actual xml text looks like.

[1] https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a31c107f59298053e4ff17fd09b2fa617b75c1ba/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextReader.cs#L2221

Comment: BTW: I wouldn't normally recommend downloading content from the web inside your event handler. You should probably use `HttpClient` and async/await to be more responsive.